# SyntaxError when adding TextInput to my app

Tags: react-native

I'm building an app in React Native,

When I add the `TextInput` to my code I get an **SyntaxError**:

```
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (85:6)
```

I've checked the file and all elements are closed properly and I've got no syntax error I've noticed.

What causes this error to appear?

**File**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { 
    AppRegistry,
    ListView, 
    View, 
    Text, 
    StyleSheet, 
    Image, 
    ImageBackground, 
    Button, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    TextInput, 
} from 'react-native';

import { createStackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation';

const image1 = require('./assets/card-0.png')
const image2 = require('./assets/card-2.png')
const image3 = require('./assets/card-3.png')
const image4 = require('./assets/card-4.png')
const image5 = require('./assets/card-5.png')

// Row data (hard-coded)
const rows = [
  {id: 0, club: 'Club Air', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image1},
  {id: 1, club: 'Abe', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image2},
  {id: 2, club: 'John Doe', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image3},
  {id: 3, club: 'Encore', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image4},
  {id: 4, club: 'Jimmy Whoo', genre: 'Hip Hop / R&B', image: image5},
]

// Row comparison function
const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id

// DataSource template object
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged})

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        // title: 'Alpha',
        header: null,
    };

  state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)
  }

  renderRow = (rowData) => { 
    return (

        <View style={styles.card}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}> 
                <View style={styles.innerCard}>
                    <Image 
                        style={styles.imageCard} 
                        source={rowData.image}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.innerText}>
                        {rowData.club}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.outerCard}>
                    <Text style={styles.outerText}>
                        {rowData.genre}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.outerTexts}>
                       View
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            value={this.state.text}
            />
        </View>
        <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: '50%',
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#DD016B',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  card: {
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  innerCard: {
    height:110,
  },
  imageCard: {
    width: 500,
    height: 150,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0, 
    marginBottom:0, 
    marginTop: 0,
  },
  innerText: {
    color: 'white',
    marginBottom: 0,
    fontSize: 35,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 100,
  },
  outerText: {
    color: '#DD016B',
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginTop: 50,
    width: 100,
  },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)

export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render() method has to return only one element. The solution is simple:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
              style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
              value={this.state.text}
            />
        </View>
        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
    )
}
```

has to become

```
render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
   </View>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I put the `ListView` in the `View` It doesn't render the list. Do you know the cause?

Comment: Got the answer, just needed the `View` to `ScrollView`. Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! I can suggest reading the reactjs docs since that's actually a react question and not a react-native question. You'll learn alot there and it will save you much time!